# Canny edge detection - OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, edge-detection

Can someone please explain why the Canny Edge Detector avaialable in OpenCV produces what appears to be greyscale results?

I am running the cv2.Canny function on the Python interface, here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('foreground_output.jpg',0)
highthresh = 250
lowthresh = 100
edges = cv2.Canny(img,lowthresh,highthresh)

plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJPLW.png) is my result. I was under the impression that the results would be a black and white binary image (edge or non edge) could someone please explain why they are not.

Comment: can you verify the assumed values by displaying (edges<255) - (edges==0)? maybe its just a rendering/displaying problem?

Comment: when I look at the image you provided, I see black image with white lines, which is in line with the Canny results I'm used to.